# C# Regex to obtain string up until a pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I've always been really bad when it comes to using regular expressions but it is something I want to seriously understand because as we all know, it is quite useful.

This is for a personal project, to keep my folders organized and neat.

I have a bunch of folders with the following naming pattern XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXX.SYY.EYY.SOMETHINGELSE
There can be any amount of X repeating separated by ".", but the SYY.EYY is always there. So what I want is a regular expression to retrieve all the text represented by XXX without the "." if possible up until the SYY.EYY pattern.

I managed to detect the pattern because YY are always numbers, so doing something like \d{2} will detect it but I'm wondering if its possible to also add the rest of the pattern to that \d{2}.

Any help is appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the YY is as you stated 2 digits and you want to get the text except the `.` up until for example `S11.E22` you could make use of the `\G` anchor and a capturing group to get the text without a dot.

The value is in the [Match.Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups?view=netframework-4.8) property.

```
\G(?!S[0-9]{2}\.E[0-9]{2})([^.]+)\.
```

In parts

- `\G` Assert position at the end of previous match (start at the beginning)
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not

  - `S[0-9]{2}\.E[0-9]{2}` Math S, 2 digits, `.` E and 2 digits
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^.]+` Match 1+ times any char except a dot
- `)` Close group 1
- `\.` Match dot literal

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cG%28%3f!S%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%5c.E%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%29%28%5b%5e.%5d%2b%29%5c.&i=XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXX.S11.E22.SOMETHINGELSE) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/o2dov7)

For example

```
string pattern = @"\G(?!S[0-9]{2}\.E[0-9]{2})([^.]+)\.";
string input = @"XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXX.S11.E22.SOMETHINGELSE";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Output

```
XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXX
XXXXXX
```

Comment: This actually worked perfectly, I didn't have the time to test it. But yes! it was perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can "replace/cut" the "." with C#.

The regex to get up until the SYY.EYY can be like this:

```
.SYY.EYY$
```

> Line ends with word -> Regex:     ExampleWord$

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
var leftPart = Regex.Match(x, "^.*?(?=SYY)").Captures.First().Value;
// this now has XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXX.
// And we can:

var left = leftPart.Replace(".", " "); // or any other char
```